# Set semi-transparent drawable on top of TextView at runtime

Tags: android, drawable

In an application to manage the costs of a living community, an user can 'terminate' a month, which is then stored in a database.

In a specific `Activity` of this app, there are shown the last four months including their attribute 'terminated'. I want to show this to the user by putting a semi-transparent hook on top of the `TextView` containing this month. Consider this image as example:

[image]

It seems that this doesn't work properly in Android.

```
textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(...)
```

does put the image on top, and it's semi-transparent too, but the initial text of the TextView disappears. Additionally, since now I haven't discovered yet how to scale the image into that TextView.

This is the actual output:

[image]

Can anybody help me with that? Should I define the scaling parameters directly in the XML layout file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a `FrameLayout` that wrap your `TextView` and an `ImageView`. The `ImageView` will contains the semitransparent drawable. In this way the will overlap